# How to handle the following null safety? The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'. Try adding a null check ('!')

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image: I am trying to solve this null safety. can anyone tell me how to handle it?]

Above mentioned code image is having a problem.

Comment: Copy and paste the code as text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`currentUser` is a property of type `User?` which means it can return null, therefore you need to do:

```
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Comment: thanks... there was one more fix along with your answer but it helped me a lot...

Comment: Actually i was using aysnc-await in initstate... it worked by removing async-await

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkCurruntUser();
  }

  void _checkCurruntUser() {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    _updateUser(user);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Firebase `currentUser` returns nullable `User` i.e. `User?`. That means you could either do

```dart
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

or

```dart
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```